Is a Random Variable Absolutely Continuous if and only if so is its CDF?
Given a probability triple $(S,\Sigma,P)$, an absolutely continuous random variable $X$ is one for which $X_*P \ll \lambda$, where $X_*P$ is the pushforward measure of $X$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ i.e. if there exists some function $f$ for which
$$P(X\in A) = P\circ X^{-1}(A) = X_*P(A) = \int_A f\ d\lambda \ \ \ \ \forall A.$$
The usual example of a non-absolutely continuous random variable is the Cantor distribution. Noting that the Cantor function is not absolutely continuous, we may ask if a random variable $X$ is continuous if and only if its CMD $F_X$ is absolutely continuous.
It seems that $F_X$ being absolutely continuous is sometimes used as the definition for an absolutely continuous random variable.

See this recent question on definition of continuous random variables.

A random variable is called continuous when it's cdf is a continuous function. In some applied contexts, and in undergraduate courses, mostly continuous random variables are considered those that have pdfs (implying their cdfs are absolutely continuous), which is not accurate as such a definition ignores continuous singular distributions (such as Cantor distribution) and those that are convex combinations of continuous singular distributions and absolutely continuous distributions. Some authors sometimes call random variables with pdfs absolutely continuous.

See here

@Mr.GandalfSauron this answers my question in the affirmative, right? Wikipedia doesn't cite a source for the claim. Do you know where I could find a proof?

@Sam Yes it does. Any good measure theory books must have it. You can search in Folland or Bogachev or try in Krishna B. Athreya and Soumendra Lahiri's Measure Theory and Probability.
